# Bamboo custom deployment-project variables

Tags: bamboo

In Bamboo, I want so take a build-release and deploy it on a target host. The target host should be variable.

As far as I know, it is not possible to run deployment-projects with customized deployment-variables (as it is possible to override plan-variables on custom-builds). My question is: is that true and if yes, what is the best way to achieve what I want?

Here are some thoughts I had during research regarding this issue:

- I could use a plan-variable "host" in my build job and always customize it as needed. Then I write this variable into a file that will be declared as a build-artifact. In my deployment-tasks I use the "Inject Bamboo variables configuration" task to get the variable. This solution has the disadvantage, that I always have to run a build, even if the artifacts do not change.
- Global variables are not feasible because they are not build-dependent. Therefore I can not use them for my task. The reason is that it could happen that they get overwritten by another build.

Are there any better solutions/thoughts on this task?

Comment: I asked this question on the atlassian-questioning-system, too, but also got no answer there. For me the best compromise was to write needed variables via my build into an artifact and then read this artifact via "Inject Bamboo variables configuration".

Answer (score 1):

> target host should be variable

No, each host is a separate environment. Otherwise the notion of "promoting an environment" breaks apart. This may be a lot of work to implement and therefore I strongly advise using bamboo specs (in Java).

> it is not possible to run deployment-projects with customized deployment-variables

I confirm: it's not possible. And again, it would break the notion of environment promotion. Rule of thumb: your environment setup should be immutable: no variable variance. The only difference b/n runs is the artifacts that are to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables in 'Other environment settings' in deployment project while configuring Environment. This way you will not have to run build when artifacts don't change.  Just change variable value before deploying the artifact.